# Get values after idxmin(1)

Tags: python, pandas

I apply `idxmin()` to get the index of the minimum absolute value of two columns:

```
rep["OffsetFrom"] = rep[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]].abs().idxmin(axis=1).dropna()
```

```
    OffsetDates OffsetDays  OffsetFrom
0       0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1       1.0     1.0         OffsetDates
2       4.0     -3.0        OffsetDays
3       4.0     -3.0        OffsetDays
4       6.0     -1.0        OffsetDays
... ... ... ...
1165    0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1166    0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1167    0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1168    0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1169    0.0     0.0         OffsetDates
1170 rows × 3 columns
```

How do I get a column of the actual values after that?
PS. This one wouldn't work, since I need to keep the original signs:

```
rep[["OffsetFrom", "Offset"]] = rep[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]].abs().agg(['idxmin','min'], axis=1)
```

Edit:
Eventually, I've simply done it with `apply`:

```
def get_abs_min_keep_sign(x):
    return min(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)

rep["Offset"] = rep[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]].apply(get_abs_min_keep_sign, axis=1)
```

However, there must be a more elegant approach out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) by column `Offset`:

```
rep["Offset"] = rep[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]].abs().idxmin(axis=1)
    
idx, cols = pd.factorize(rep['Offset'])
rep["OffsetVal"] = rep.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(rep)), idx]
```

Another numpy solution is use [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) for positions by absolute values, then is possible use indexing by array by columns names for `Offset` and for values is used indexing by `rep[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]]` converted to 2d array:

```
cols = ["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]

pos = np.argmin(rep[cols].abs().to_numpy(), axis=1)
rep["Offset2"] = np.array(cols)[pos]
rep["OffsetVal2"] = rep[cols].to_numpy()[np.arange(len(rep.index)),pos]
print (rep)
   OffsetDates  OffsetDays       Offset  OffsetVal      Offset2  OffsetVal2
0          0.0         0.0  OffsetDates        0.0  OffsetDates         0.0
1          1.0         1.0  OffsetDates        1.0  OffsetDates         1.0
2          4.0        -3.0   OffsetDays       -3.0   OffsetDays        -3.0
3          4.0        -3.0   OffsetDays       -3.0   OffsetDays        -3.0
4          6.0        -1.0   OffsetDays       -1.0   OffsetDays        -1.0
```

Your function should be simplify:

```
rep["OffsetVal"] = rep[["OffsetDates","OffsetDays"]].apply(lambda x: min(x,key=abs),axis=1)
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I think that answers my question, although the apply version still seem a bit easier on eyes (true on simplification btw)

Answer (score 1):

You need check adding `to_numpy` to remove the column impact and with `lambda`

```
df[["OffsetFrom", "Offset"]] = df[["OffsetDates", "OffsetDays"]].agg([lambda x : x.abs().idxmin(),'min'], axis=1).to_numpy()
df
Out[889]: 
   OffsetDates  OffsetDays   OffsetFrom  Offset
0          0.0         0.0  OffsetDates     0.0
1          1.0         1.0  OffsetDates     1.0
2          4.0        -3.0   OffsetDays    -3.0
3          4.0        -3.0   OffsetDays    -3.0
4          6.0        -1.0   OffsetDays    -1.0
```

Panda dataframe assign will match the `index` and `column` , when the column different, will return `NaN`

Comment: Thank you, it works. What do you mean by "`to_numpy` to remove the column impact", making a "deep" copy or something? Cause it seems to be running well even without `to_numpy`

Comment: @shab-jab no worry here you do not need , but if you assign to the existing column , and column name different will return NaN

Comment: Wait, just realized, it is still finding the minimal value itself. I need to pick the one whose absolute value is the lowest. But keeping the sign